# Having trouble multiplying a number using Arel Table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, arel

I'm trying to construct a query that needs to adjust a number by a percentage, like 80% would be * 0.80.

I can multiply by an integer:

```
Arel::Nodes::Multiplication.new(Inventory.arel_table[:available].sum, 3).to_sql

=> "SUM(\"inventories\".\"available\") * 3"
```

I get an error when I try to multiply by a float.

```
Arel::Nodes::Multiplication.new(Inventory.arel_table[:available].sum, 3.1).to_sql

RuntimeError: unsupported: Float
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Arel::Nodes::Multiplication.new(Inventory.arel_table[:available].sum, Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new('0.80')).to_sql  this works....

Answer (score 1):

```rb
Arel::Nodes::Multiplication.new(
  Inventory.arel_table[:available].sum,
  Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new('0.80')
).to_sql
```